# Resetting $HOST after some other command modified it

Tags: hosts

Anaconda incorrectly overwrites the `$HOST` variable which seems to be caused by this [anaconda bug](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7031#issuecomment-387725070). It exports `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu` as the `HOST`. This probably occurs only when ran inside `.bashrc` to initialize the terminal. Simply exporting `localhost` as the host, mostly fixes it e.g.:

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/kmourat/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/kmourat/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/kmourat/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/kmourat/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<

# TEMP FIX
export HOST=localhost
```

But is there a more appropriate way to do this? Something like "re-running" the `/etc/hosts`?

(This came out when running `npm start` for a react app and it opened a browser window at `http://x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu:3000/` instead of `http://localhost:3000/`)

Comment: `export HOST=$(hostname)` maybe?

Comment: If anaconda's init messes with other environment variables from `/etc/hosts` does this fix reset them as well (some side-effect maybe?), or it just changes the `HOST`? Edit: It seems it doesn't, only overwrites the host variable, which doesn't seem better to me as `localhost` ends up not pointing to same place as $hostname.

Comment: Save the value of `$HOST` before running `anaconda` in another variable (e.g. $hosttemp) and reassign it afterwards.

Comment: The old host only holds "localhost", but I guess this is the correct answer. Even more so since it is simple, and it seems too tedious to check all variables for side-effects.