# Why does my machine display a different hostname?

Tags: zsh

I installed ZSH today and whenever I use it, my hostname changes.

Outside of ZSH it is:

```
mus@MyMachine
```

However, when I run `zsh` it then displays as:

```
mus@x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
```

I have searched for a reason online but can't seem to find anything that addresses it.

When I try `hostname` (whilst running ZSH) to check if it has been changed, it returns:

```
MyMachine
```

This indicates that my hostname *hasn't* changed, yet it still displays as:

```
mus@x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
```

It takes up a lot more screen space than I would like and makes my CLI messy, which is why I would like to change (or even revert) it if possible.

Why is this happening?  Is this something I can / need to change?

Comment: You can configure your zsh prompt as you like http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_14.html

Comment: Okay, I'll look into that. The main thing I want to know is *why* it changed in the first place.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy Your hostname didn't change. When you install a new shell like zsh, or fish, they will have their own way of displaying a prompt. Some show the directory, some don't. Some show the hostname, some don't. There are [plenty](https://medium.com/wearetheledger/oh-my-zsh-made-for-cli-lovers-installation-guide-3131ca5491fb), of [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084210/how-to-change-the-prompt-in-oh-my-zsh-and-add-hostname-to-it) on the [internet](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jazz-up-your-zsh-terminal-in-seven-steps-a-visual-guide-e81a8fd59a38/) how to change it.

Comment: @darksky That's the thing; as I highlight a number of times in my question, I didn't think that the hostname *had* changed. What I wanted to know was why it was displayed as something other than what I knew it to be. Since posting, however, I have read a lot on the matter and I now understand why this happened. Also, change your comment to an answer and I'll accept as this is helpful nonetheless.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy okay, see my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're referring to is called a **prompt**. Every shell has their default way of displaying this. For Bash, it is

```
username@hostname:/current/working/directory$
```

When you run ZSH for the first time, you should get a menu asking you to create a configuration. By selecting (2) to populate your ~/.zshrc with the recommended configuration, you'd get the default prompt that looks like

```
username@HOST /current/working/directory
 %
```

Note that in addition to `hostname` which is the name of your machine, there is such a thing as `HOST` environment variable. You can print it by `echo $HOST`. This is what you see in your ZSH prompt. In you case, it seems you've installed Anaconda, and according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150737/resetting-host-after-some-other-command-modified-it), this variable gets set to `x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu` after a `conda` environment activation. You can of course manually reset it back by adding

```
export HOST=$(hostname)
```

to the end of your `~/.zshrc`.

One of the most well known and elaborate ways to customize the ZSH prompt is using what's called [Oh-My-ZSH](https://ohmyz.sh/). As you can find on their website, it is installed simply by

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh)"
```

You will find that with Oh-My-ZSH, the possibilities with customization are endless. [Here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes) you can find many themes to choose from.